# saddle point and oscillation function

Tags: calculus

I read a paper that
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{s \sqrt{\cos (x)}-2 x} \, dx=\frac{4 \sqrt{\pi } e^s}{s^{3/2}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^s}{\sqrt{s}}-\frac{4 e^s}{s}$$
I try to calculate the saddle point but I do not have lucky...

Comment: Where did you find this expression ? It looks like a truncated series expansion. Just curious. Cheers.

Comment: The saddle-point method is usually used for approximations. How were you going to use it to obtain the exact value of the integral? Or is what you wrote as an equation actually meant to be an approximation?

Comment: For $s=0$, the left hand side is $\frac12$, while the right hand side blows up to $+\infty$. Is this perhaps an asymptotic expansion as $s\to\infty$?